# Workaround for Android bug pertaining to setRetainInstance(true)

Tags: android, android-fragments

Please check out this issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20791

The project (https://github.com/kaciula/BugRetain) uses a CursorLoader to take 2 values from a database through a content provider and shows them on screen. The scenario is this: From activity A, go to activity B, switch once the orientation and go back to activity A. The values from db are no longer showing.

Can anyone provide a workaround for this issue? The problem doesn't appear with only CursorLoader but with any loader. As a consequence of this bug, I can't write an app with fragments that use setRetainInstance and is available in both orientations. I really need a workaround until the Android guys fix the issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not set your fragments as retainable if you use Loaders. If you need to store some data between configuration changes, create another retainable fragment and pass this data to him.

A similar example can be found here: [FragmentRetainInstanceSupport](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentRetainInstanceSupport.html). But this example uses extra fragment for threading purposes. In your case this extra fragment will be used as data container.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but the problem is still there. In the non-UI fragment I use setRetainInstance(true) and use a CursorLoader to get the data and then pass it back to the target fragment. However, if  I follow the scenario described above, the non-UI fragment doesn't pass the data back. The issue here is that when using setRetainInstance(true) and following my scenario, initLoader is called inside onActivityCreated but onLoadFinished is NEVER called after that.

Comment: You should've left your Loader in UI fragment, and only copy data that you need to be persisted between configuration changes to non-UI retained fragment.

Comment: Let me make my problem clearer. The use case I want to fix is one where I have a fragment with setRetainInstance(true) and a loader in the same fragment. I want to retain the fragment so that, if the loader is in the process of loading, if I switch orientation, the fragment reconnects with the loader and does not make the loader start all over again. This works perfectly but if I go through the scenario described in my question, the loader is not returning any results (and I need fresh results because the data changed while in the other screen).

Comment: You don't have to use retained fragment in order for Loader to retain its data. Take a look at 4th point at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html: "They automatically reconnect to ...."

Comment: Hmm. It seems what you're saying is true now. A couple of months ago I have made various tests with previous ACL versions and found that I need to use setRetainInstance. But with the latest ACL revision (currently 4), it works as expected. No need for setRetainInstance. Thanks for the patience.